# Is it possible to build jQuery with a subset of the components? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, build

just wondering if it possible to build the jQuery library with **just a selection of components**:

**e.g. without Effects or Manipulation?**

---

## Sounds like it would be mission impossible!! :)

Thanks everyone!

---

#### Reason:

I read somewhere a long time ago about jquery being modular since version 1.4.x . Not being able to find anything on jQuery.com and elsewhere I gave up and came here.

Like always the answers are always helpful, even though a question doesn't have an answer.

---

Any ideas? Thanks guys :)

Comment: What's your use-case for this? ie, why do you _need_ it? Or is it just curiosity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not without modifying the source yourself.** *(which I recommend against)*

John Resig **WAS** going to do this because of jQuery Mobile but they decided on one large bundle. Just use theversion hosted by Google's CDN and you shouldn't have to worry too much about load speed, chances are it'll already be in the user's cache.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find the duplicate right now but the bottom line is no, it's not possible without huge effort; but it doesn't matter, because it's loaded just once, and if there were any serious performance advantages to gain, the <strike>founding fathers</strike> jQuery developers would have created a provision for it.

Comment: Agreed, it would be an awful lot of error prone and painful effort to save some KB of the jQuery file.  If you ever wanted to upgrade jQuery, you'd have to do it all over again.  Not worth it.  Just link the Google CDN, jQuery will be cached for a good number of your users.

Comment: Yeah, you had to edit your answer to keep up with mine. Bahahah! :p

Comment: @Marko nope, we actually had the same idea at the same time. :) (I said the very same thing in a dupe a few weeks back)

Comment: Hahha I'm just being cheeky mate :)

Comment: @Marko I know, but I also know it itches a bit when somebody edits to reflect something you just wrote. :)

Comment: @Pekka I know right! I see it all the time, some answers even `quote` other answers. Ah well, all in the name of helping others :)

Comment: haha you guys are cool, btw how do you add text `highlighting` in the comments?

Comment: @Radiant use backticks: `\`` asterisks for *italic*: `*word*` two asterisks for **bold**: `**word**`

Comment: @Pekka: thanks!! Well now I need to tick an answer... :) I'll tick the one with highest votes in 1 hour. :P

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be possible, but it would take a ton of work.  Many of the methods inside the jquery library are dependent on eachother - it would take hours and hours of debugging to get a non-broken version.  You are better off just including everything - it's not that large of a resource hog anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Developer time is more important and fiddling for that task is gonna be expensive :)

I suggest that you just use the one on Google's hosted, most of the time its already cached on their browsers

My favorite version btw is 1.2.6 and packed
http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `1.2.6` in particular? :)